# $.getScript and var return

Tags: jquery

I've a problem with $.getScript that dosen't seem to interact with my primary script :

```
var noFocus = true; 

$(document).keydown(function (e) {

alert(noFocus);
$.getScript("myscript.js");

});
```

and myscript.js :

```
noFocus = false;
```

But on keydown the alert is ever true...  ?

Comment: Maybe describe what you want to achieve, because all this can be done without a `getScript`!

Comment: Where is your "noFocus" ? Is this whole block in a $(document).ready ? If yes, noFocus is not in the global scope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var noFocus = true;

var myFuncX = function(){
  alert("myFuncX " +noFocus);
}

$(document).keydown(function (e) {

  alert("B " + noFocus);
  $.getScript("myscript.js");
  alert("A " +noFocus);

});


myscript.js:

noFocus = false;
myFuncX();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the page first to give focus and then press a key. You might want to change the keydown event to something else for it to be useful.